# If $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{S}^n,\mathbb{S}^n)$ and $\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=0$, then $f(x_0)=x_0$ and $f(y_0)=-y_0$ for some $x_0, y_0$.

Tags: differential-topology, fixed-point-theorems

> If $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{S}^n,\mathbb{S}^n)$ and $\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=0$, where $\mathbb{S}^n=\left \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:\|x\|=1\right \}$. Prove that there exist two points $x_0, y_0\in \mathbb{S}^n$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$ and $f(y_0)=-y_0$.

This is an exercise on the chapter about mod 2 degrees and Borsuk-Ulam theorem in a Differential Topology book (Chinese version). I think that [a question I asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488391/if-f-in-mathcalc-mathbbsn-mathbbsn-and-f-is-not-surjective-then) is a special case of this exercise. Because, if $\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=1$, then $f$ must be surjective.

Let $g(x)=f(-x)$. Using smooth approximation of $f$ and the definition of $\mathrm{deg}_2$ for smooth functions through regular values, I think I can prove that $\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=\mathrm{deg}_2(g)$. So, it suffices to find a fixed-point for $f$. But I don’t know how to proceed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know how do you formulate these problems or even how do you define degree using differential topology but in Algebraic Topology, if there is no point $a$ with $f(a) = -a$ then you can homotope the map $f(x)$ to identity map and hence it has degree $1$. Similarly if there is no point $a$ with $f(a) = a$ then you can homotope the map $f(x)$ to antipodal map $x \to -x$ which makes the degree $-1^n$. In either case it's not $0$. I am sure there is equivalent of this using differential techniques. But how easy or difficult it is, I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Rishi Thanks for your comment. I think I've got the proof using your hint. Whatever my definition of degree is, it is invariant under homotopies. Taking "$f(x)=x$ for no $x$" for example, then $G(t,x)=tf(x)+(1-t)(-x)$ will not take the value $0$, so $F(t,x)=G(t,x)/\|G(t,x)\|$ is the homotopy connecting $f$ and the antipodal map. Is this reason OK? I'm not good at geometric stuffs and haven't learnt about Algebraic Topology. I hope that I've made things correct.

Comment: Yes, that's how you get homotopies in those cases.

Comment: @Rishi Thank you very much! Now the problem is solved! If you're willing to write a short answer, I'll accept it. If you don't have spare time, that is OK, too. I'll write a detailed answer when I have time. Thanks again!

Comment: Your earlier comment seems to me like a detailed answer once you include the case where it is homotopic to identity. What more details do you need?

Comment: @Rishi Ah, you're right. I don't need more details than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a community-wiki answer illustrating @Rishi's comments under the question I asked. This is the first time that I write a community-wiki answer, please feel free to edit it if anything is inappropriate.

We prove the exercise by contradiction. Assume that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb S^n$, then we prove that $f$ is homotopic to the antipodal map $j:\mathbb S^n\to\mathbb S^n, x\mapsto -x$. Indeed, define
$$G: [0,1]\times \mathbb S^n\to\mathbb R^{n+1},\qquad (t,x)\mapsto tf(x)+(1-t)(-x),$$
then $G(t,x)\neq 0$ for all $(t,x)\in[0,1]\times \mathbb S^n$: if $G(t,x)=0$ then $tf(x)=(1-t)x$, so $t=\|tf(x)\|=\|(1-t)x\|=1-t$, which implies that $t=1-t$ and $f(x)=x$; recall that we have assumed that $f(x)\neq x$ for all $x\in\mathbb S^n$ (Here $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean metric in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$.) Hence, the map
$$F(t,x)=\frac{G(t,x)}{\|G(t,x)\|},\qquad (t,x)\in[0,1]\times \mathbb S^n$$
is a homotopy connecting $f$ and $j$. Since $\mathrm{deg}_2$ is invariant under homotopies, we then have $\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=\mathrm{deg}_2(j)=1$, contradicting with "$\mathrm{deg}_2(f)=0$". Therefore, there exists some $x_0\in\mathbb S^n$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.

Similarly, if $f(x)\neq -x$ for all $x\in\mathbb S^n$, then we can prove that $f$ is homotopic to the identity map $i:\mathbb S^n\to\mathbb S^n, x\mapsto x$, which is a contradiction, too. So, there exists some $y_0\in\mathbb S^n$ such that $f(y_0)=-y_0$. This completes the proof of this exercise.

*Remark.* After learning the concept of [(oriented) degrees](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_mapping), the same argument proves the following exercise:

> Let $f\in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb S^n,\mathbb S^n)$, then
>
> - if $\mathrm{deg}(f)\neq 1$, then there exists some $x_0\in\mathbb S^n$ such that $f(x_0)=-x_0$;
> - if $\mathrm{deg}(f)\neq (-1)^{n+1}$, then there exists some $x_0\in\mathbb S^n$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$.

(Note that $S^n\subset \mathbb R^{n+1}$, so $\mathrm{deg}(j)=(-1)^{n+1}$.)