# What is my mistake? Degree of a map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Question 2 on page 11 of J. P. May's "A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology" reads:

Show that any map $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ with $\text{deg}(f)\neq 1$ has a fixed point.

I have shown that if $f$ has no fixed point, then $\text{deg}(f)=-1.$ This contradicts the desired result. Where is my mistake? To be clear, I am $\textit{not}$ looking for a solution to the problem.

MY ATTEMPT: Suppose $f$ has no fixed point. Define the homotopy $f_t:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ by
\begin{align*}
f_t(x)=\frac{(1-t)f(x)-tx}{|(1-t)f(x)-tx|}.
\end{align*}
This is a well-defined homotopy from $f(x)$ to $-x$ so long as the denominator does not vanish.

To see this is the case, suppose for contradiction we have $t\in I$ and $x\in S^1$ such that $(1-t)f(x)-tx=0.$ This implies $|(1-t)f(x)|=|tx|,$ which implies $|1-t|=|t|,$ which implies $t=1/2.$ Plugging this into $(1-t)f(x)-tx=0,$ we obtain $f(x)/2=x/2.$ This contradicts our assumption that $f$ has no fixed point.

We conclude that $f_t$ is indeed a well-defined homotopy from $f(x)$ to $-x,$ showing that $\text{deg}(f)=-1.$

Comment: Your idea is correct. Note that the degree of the map $x\mapsto -x$ is $(-1)^2=1$. See my earlier post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491559/if-f-in-mathcalc-mathbbsn-mathbbsn-and-mathrmdeg-2f-0-then/4494493#4494493

Comment: Thank you, I was mixing up the antipodal map with the reflection map.

Comment: The degree of the antipodal map on $S^n$ is $(-1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You showed correctly that $f$ is homotopic to the map $-id : S^1 \to S^1, -id(x) = -x$. But it is not true that $\deg (-id) = -1$. In fact, $-id$ is a rotation (angle of rotation = $\pi$) which is homotopic to $id$. An explicit homotopy from $id$ to $-id$ is given by
$$H(x,t) = e^{\pi i t}x.$$